# Performance impact of IntelliJ IDEA vs NetBeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, netbeans, performance-testing

So, recently I've resumed my studies (2nd year HS) and in this year we'll be using Java as the primarily language for everything; I've been using Java independently for about a year and I love IntelliJ, however our teacher just **refuses** to even take a look at it, just demands to use NetBeans, regardless of the several *technical* arguments I've had with her.

She argues that it's because the computers are fairly old and crappy (which they are) but with that in mind, is that really a meaningful argument to give?
My ASUS laptop can handle IntelliJ pretty well with 16GB of RAM, as you can see here:

[image: task manager]

However, due to some weird installation problems I can't personally test NetBeans (yuck), and I'm not a fan of downgrading my RAM to 4GB (The capacity of the school's computers).

So my question is, would the performance impact of IntelliJ be substantial enough to justify the use of NetBeans, even though IDEA it's (In my opinion) a much better IDE?
And if so, wouldn't something *lighter* like Eclipse make more sense?

Comment: While I cannot attest to IntelliJ, but have used NetBeans in the past - when I finally made the switch to Eclipse - I'd never go back to NetBeans - ditto the fact that Eclipse works with a number of other languages!

Comment: Non-programming advice: sometimes it makes sense to push back against bad decisions, and sometimes it makes sense to just let them be. Pick your battles, as the saying goes. Fwiw, I've been in the industry almost a decade and I don't think I've seen anyone use Netbeans. A lot of intellij, a lot of eclipse, and one guy who just used emacs... but no Netbeans. Ymmv of course. ;)

Comment: @JGlass NetBeans works with numerous languages either!

Comment: I think what really sparked my initial debate with her is the fact that you can't program with whatever IDE you prefer since that's why there are several of them, and not just one **Be all**; yes yes I know there are some certainly reasonable standards, but after all, it's just a .java file, ran by the JVM, but thanks guys for the interest! :D

Comment: This question will be closed for sure... Just use whatever you want. Requiring certain IDE is mostly unnecessary unless you need a certain feature. Teachers often use bad tools. I don't see why school's old PCs should matter if you have your own.  Also, Eclipse would not make sense since it is a bad IDE.

Comment: @HMD - oh, I didnt realize that, thank you.

Comment: All three IDEs enable a stable of plugins/extensions. You are almost certainly not making use of many of them. Disabling those unused extensions can cut back significantly on memory use, startup time, and CPU demand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no straightforward answer to your question:

IntelliJ IDEA is a great Java IDE. Its main advantage over NetBeans and Eclipse is the better support for Android development (Android Studio which is built on IntelliJ IDEA became the official IDE for Android in 2013). In contrast to Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA and NetBeans offer a more comprehensive range of out-of-the-box functions that making it easier for beginners. There are more plug-ins available each for IntelliJ IDEA and for Eclipse than for NetBeans. These are just some of the advantages of IntelliJ IDEA.

IntelliJ IDEA is a commercial product (although some parts are open source, but development is not driven by the community). For those who pay for a Java IDE, the higher memory requirements will probably not be a problem. Unlike Eclipse and NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA's Git integration is realized by delegation to the Git command line (instead of using JGit), which has also some disadvantages. By default, files are automatically saved, but compiled before starting. Some like that, others prefer incremental compilation on saving as in Eclipse. Which one is the best Java IDE depends on the user's usage and preferences.

To answer your question, the higher memory requirement at only 4 GB of available RAM (your screenshot shows `637.3 MB / 4096 MB = 15.6 %` only for the (idle?) IDE) is a valid argument against IntelliJ IDEA (especially when you consider that the memory requirements will continue to increase with each new version), but not an argument for NetBeans. The decision was certainly made not only because of this single argument. I would probably have given the arguments a different weighting and come to a different decision as your teacher.

However, you should appreciate the teacher explaining her decision. I guess you won't convince her to revise her decision. But why not develop at home with your favorite IDE and show/review the code to/with your teacher in her favorite IDE? You would get to know the advantages and disadvantages of at least two Java IDEs. Nobody is more annoying than those guys that tell people using the wrong thing just because it's not the thing they prefer.

> [A Mac user, an IntelliJ user, and a vegan walk into a bar. How do I
>   know? Well after 2 minutes THE WHOLE F'ING BAR KNEW!](https://twitter.com/lukaseder/status/621203966634917888)

Answer (score 1):

Let's not talk about Eclipse and stick to NetBeans and IDEA. Cause I thing Eclipse is not match for these two at all! I guess It is good just for its lightness.

IDEA is not necessarily better IDE than NetBeans, I guess it's all about the magnitude of program you want to develop.

Netbeans is so much more lighter, faster, more intelligent and its features for network programming are amazing.

In other hand, IDEA is truly a great IDE for developing big softwares. It is more stable, more powerful, it has more functionality, and it has plugins that you can use without any worries.

As someone who has used both of them, I think Both are great, but I prefer Netbeans for light programs.

Comment: NetBeans is much much interactive and handy than Eclipse  but I need to have InteliiJ IDEA cause of slowness of NetBeans. Thank you